# Firebase with AngularFire, ordered and limited join

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I'm using AngularFire 2.0.2, and it uses the Firebase SDK 3.x.
Since there is no `fire-utils` for this version, I'm trying to create a normalized collection by hand (specifically an ordered and limited join).

I have a structure like this:

```
users: {
  user_1: {
    name:...,
    groups: {
      group_1: true,
      group_2: true,
      ...
    }
  },
  ...
},

groups: {
  group_1: {
    group_name: ...,
    last_edited: servertimestamp
  },
  group_2: {
    group_name: ...,
    last_edited: servertimestamp
  }, 
  ...
}
```

I want to get the first 10 groups of a user ordered by `last_edited` timestamp.

What's the best approach to do that? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the best way, but when I had to do this recently, this is what I did. (I've unpacked the anonymous functions here, because I find they sometimes confuse things)

Firstly, look up your user:

```
user = $firebaseObject( firebase.database().ref().child('users').child(username) );
```

then use the AngularFire $loaded method to check when it's loaded and tell it what to do next:

```
user .$loaded().then( lookupGroups );
```

Then create a function called lookupGroups to do the next lookup. This will make an empty array and then loop over all of the groups using angular.forEach

```
function lookupGroups (){
    $scope.groups= [];
    angular.forEach(user.groups, getGroupData);
}
```

then write your final getGroupData function which takes the groupid, looks it up and adds the group data to your groups array

```
function getArkData(key, value){
    grouppath = firebase.database().ref().child('groups').child(value)
    groupData = $firebaseObject( grouppath  );
    $scope.groups.push( groupData );
}
```

Then you have a $scope.groups array available to use in your front end.

As I say, there might be better ways (I'd be interested to see if anyone has a better way), but this seemed to work for me.

Comment: the problem i'm seeing here is when you have thousand of groups, you're requesting all the groups. But at the end the idea is to get only 10 results depending on the group data. thanks for the answer Simon!

Comment: I agree with you, and I'm always suspicious with nosql and long-polling, but you might be surprised by how fast the long polling in Firebase makes searches like this.